# Sorting doesnt work c++

Tags: c++, sorting

```
for (Dodavatel *a : zoznamDodavatelov) {
    for (Dodavatel *b : zoznamDodavatelov) {
        if (a->getNazov() < a->getNazov()) {
            Dodavatel *prem = a;
            a = b;
            b = prem;
        }
    }
}
```

why doesn't this work, it can't sort my array called `zoznamDodavatelov`

Comment: `if (a->getNazov() < a->getNazov())` looks a bit suspicious, don't you think?

Comment: How is `zoznamDodavatelov` declared? How come its declaration is not included in your question?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `std::sort`, and not this awful bubble sort?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it appears to your containers store pointers of `Dodavatel *` types. However, in your cycles pointers `a` and `b` are declared as independent local variables. Swapping around pointers `a` and `b` does not affect the contents of your array.

So, the question is: what are you supposed to reorder in order to "sort" the array? The pointers? Or the objects these pointers point to?

In the former case in order to reorder the pointers you need to declare the cycle variables as references

```
for (Dodavatel *&a : zoznamDodavatelov) {
  for (Dodavatel *&b : zoznamDodavatelov) {
```

In the latter case you can can keep the current declaration, but inside your `if` you have to swap `*a` and `*b`, not `a`, and `b`.

Secondly, your `if` makes no sense since it compares `*a` with itself.

Answer (score 1):

> if (a->getNazov() < a->getNazov()) {

this line will never be true.

Comment: That's true, but it's just a typo; @AnT has noticed the more significant issue.